# Spring MVC: configure properties from before bean creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I have a scenario where I want to programmatically inject properties into Spring before any beans are created/initialized:

1. The beans (not modifiable) are configured with `ConditionalOnProperty`, so properties need to be set before creation.
2. Properties need to be configured dynamically and programmatically, not via property file (we call an API and use the result to set the property value).

I see `ApplicationContext` has a way to get the current environment's property sources (via [ConfigurableEnvironment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html)), but I am not sure how to inject into the Spring lifecycle to configure the `ApplicationContext` before beans are initialized.

I'm aware of [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) as a hook which occurs before bean initialization, but I don't see a way to obtain an instance of `ApplicationContext` in it.

How can it be accomplished?

Note: the application itself is Spring Web/MVC, not Spring Boot. The third party library internally uses Spring Boot classes (`ConditionalOnProperty`).

Comment: If it isn't spring boot then how do you do `ConditionalOnProperty` as that is from Spring Boot and not plain spring. What do you mean with 2, what isn't configurable about property files? You place them on your file system, modify them and start the app. They don't have to  be part of the application?

Comment: Good catch...I didn't realize `ConditionalOnProperty` was Spring Boot. It turns out the third party libraries we are using (from our MVC app) internally use Spring Boot classes.

Comment: As for #2, we call an API and use the result to set the property value. I've updated the same in the question the clarify.

Comment: Just make it a propertysource or use an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to call the endpoint, prepare a `MapPropertySource` and add it to the `Environment`.

Comment: Thank you! I found a solution based on your recommendation of using `ApplicationContextInitializer` and have posted as an answer to the question. If it doesn't look right, please share! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @m-deinum's comment, I was able to get it working with the following:

```java
public class MyPropertyInitializer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebApplicationInitializer, ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        String initializerClasses = servletContext.getInitParameter(ContextLoader.GLOBAL_INITIALIZER_CLASSES_PARAM);
        String initClassName = this.getClass().getName();
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(initializerClasses)) {
            initializerClasses += "," + initClassName;
        } else {
            initializerClasses = initClassName;
        }
        servletContext.setInitParameter(ContextLoader.GLOBAL_INITIALIZER_CLASSES_PARAM, initializerClasses);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        Properties props = getCustomProperties();
        PropertySource<?> propertySource = new PropertiesPropertySource("my-custom-props", props);
        context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
    }

    protected Properties getCustomProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        // do logic to set desired values
        return props;
    }
}
```